# my computer headphone jack doesnt work

Tags: sound

I just recently bought a new Asus S200e and the headphone jack doesn't work when they are plugged in- only my computer speakers. I have tried many options but the headphones icon does not appear in the sound icon at the bottom so I can't ''enable it''.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you **edit your question** and provide more details? Like the Sound Card you are using with `lspci -nnk | grep -A6 -i audio`? The output of `pulseaudio --check`, `pulseaudio --dump-conf`, `amixer -c 0`, `pacmd dump-volumes` and `pactl info`.

Answer (score 0):

That could be something in alsamixer. (I suppose you first tried clicking on all output devices in System Settings -> Sound Settings?)

Open a terminal and enter `alsamixer`. You see a lot of faders. You can navigate with the left and right arrow keys and change the volume of each fader with the arrow keys up and down. You can mute them with `m`. Chances are one of those faders and switches is called "Line Jack Sense". Play with the settings till you have sound on your headphones. You can exit alsamixer with `Esc`.